# Why does Pythons PyObject_CallMethod increase ref count of a list argument by 4?

Tags: python, python-c-extension

I am relatively unexperienced in Python. I have to fix a bug in a legacy software and got stuck. We are using Python 2.6.6.

The problem is as follows:

There is a call in C++  as follows:

```
PyObject_CallMethod( obj, "updateCallback", "(O)", list );
```

and the (simplified) updateCallback in Python code looks like following :

```
def updateCallback(self, args):        
    print sys.getrefcount( args )
```

list is a PyObject* and before the CallMethod its refcount is 1. Right after the updateCallback is called using PyObject_CallMethod, the print statement in Python code prints 5. When the PyObject_CallMethod returns, I see in the debugger that the "list"  (AFAIK which corresponds to the args in updateCalback) has still refcount 5.

Now, I understand that the use of (O) increases the refcount by 1, but why is it 4 in my case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you step into `PyObject_CallMethod()`  in the debugger to see what happens?

Comment: Yes. I see that my PyObject has refcount 1 until args = Py_VaBuildValue(format, va); line. After this line, the refcount is 2. Then after call_function_tail it is 5. I am trying to debug call_function_tail too, but I was hoping that there is an easy answer about the Python's behavior that everybody knows (except me :) )

Comment: There are some pretty complex things going on when calling a Python function.  It might be that the frame object hasn't yet been garbage collected for some reason, or there is some kind reference cycle, so you have to wait for the next run of the garbage collector to clear this up.  I don't think there is an easy answer.

Comment: Now, refcounts being 5 at this part of the code does not disturb me really but the real problem is that this 5 never goes below this value (i.e. also not at a later time). We have a massive memory leak because of this.

Comment: Can you post a full code snippet that demonstrates the problem so we can compile and debug?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem

Comment: Don't know the answer to the actual question, but calling Py_DECREF on the object after the method call, seems to help.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777126/pyobject-callmethod-with-keyword-arguments