# PyObject_CallMethod with keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-c-api, python-embedding

I'm trying to embed a Python (2.7) library in my C application and I'm using the Python/C API to call Python code from C. I need to call a Python method that takes keyword arguments. Semantically, I'm trying to achieve the equivalent of the following line in Python:

```
myobject.dosomething('blahdy blah', somearg=True)
```

By reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/index.html), I have managed to get as far as the following, but this doesn't pass in the keyword arguments:

```
PyObject_CallMethod(myobject, "dosomething", "s", "blahdy blah");
```

I'm not super familiar with Python and I'm kind of stuck at this point as the documentation is not entirely clear on this and Google searches didn't turn up much useful info either. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: It seems like there isn't a function that calls a method with keyword arguments. At least, looking at [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2007-June/073661.html). However, `PyObject_Call` always work.

Comment: @Bakuriu: thanks for the hint! In the end, that's exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end I used [PyObject_Call](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#PyObject_Call) to do this (thanks Bakuriu for the hint!). Just in case anyone wonders how to do that, here's my code:

```
PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("(s)", "blahdy blah");    
PyObject *keywords = PyDict_New();
PyDict_SetItemString(keywords, "somearg", Py_True);

PyObject_Call(PyObject_GetAttrString(myobject, "do something"), args, keywords);
Py_DECREF(args);
Py_DECREF(keywords);
```

Comment: This has a memory leak. [`PyObject_GetAttrString`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttrString) returns a new reference. So, we need to call `Py_DECREF` once we are done calling the attribute.

Answer (score 9):

Tamas's answer will get the job done, but it will also leak memory. To avoid leaks, use

```
PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("(s)", "blahdy blah");    
PyObject *keywords = PyDict_New();
PyDict_SetItemString(keywords, "somearg", Py_True);
PyObject *myobject_method = PyObject_GetAttrString(myobject, "do something");

PyObject *result = PyObject_Call(myobject_method, args, keywords);
Py_DECREF(args);
Py_DECREF(keywords);
Py_DECREF(myobject_method);

// Do something with the result

Py_DECREF(result);
```

Of course, if there are any errors or exceptions in the Python code some of the PyObjects will be NULL and your program will probably crash. Checking for NULL results and/or using `Py_DECREFX()` can help you avoid this.

Comment: Note if you have no arguments but just want to pass in the keyword arguments say if your calling something like  `pd.to_json(orient="table")`' then you cannot pass a null to the args but instead make an empty tuple `PyObject *args = PyTuple_New(0);` and pass that in as the second argument to `PyObject_Call`